# Safe delete second EFI Partition - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, efi

I removed OpenSuse from my PC (so now I have only Windows), but there are two EFI System partitions.
Using Partdisk and `bcdedit /enum all`, I believe that Windows is using only the first EFI System partition (labeled Vol. A below, while the second partition was labeled Vol. B).

Before deleting the seemingly unuseful EFI partition, I would like to confirm if I can do it safely, mainly because I see that there is still some firmware on it:

```
Aplicativo de Firmware (101fffff)
---------------------------------
identificador           {e44d77c7-574c-11eb-b959-28cdc4f759f4}
device                  partition=B:
path                    \EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi
description             UEFI: IM2P33F3A NVMe ADATA 512GB, Partition 4
isolatedcontext         Yes
```

Here is possibly useful information from Diskpart and from `bcdedit /enum all`:

```
DISKPART> list vol

  Volume No.  Ltr  Rótulo       Fs     Tipo        Tamanho  Status     Informações
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   OS           NTFS   Partição     177 GB  Íntegro    Iniciali
* Volume 1     A   ESP          FAT32  Partição     150 MB  Íntegro    Sistema
  Volume 2     B                FAT    Partição     500 MB  Íntegro    Oculto
  Volume 3     D   WINRETOOLS   NTFS   Partição     990 MB  Íntegro    Oculto
  Volume 4     E   Image        NTFS   Partição      17 GB  Íntegro    Oculto
  Volume 5     F   DELLSUPPORT  NTFS   Partição    1321 MB  Íntegro    Oculto
```

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /enum all

Gerenciador de Inicialização de Firmware
----------------------------------------
identificador           {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bootmgr}
                        {273a1041-4467-11eb-b947-806e6f6e6963}
                        {e44d77c7-574c-11eb-b959-28cdc4f759f4}
timeout                 0

Gerenciador de Inicialização do Windows
---------------------------------------
identificador           {bootmgr}
device                  partition=A:
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  pt-BR
inherit                 {globalsettings}
isolatedcontext         Yes
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {fc253ae3-3c57-11eb-a1ba-a4bb6d714fe3}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Aplicativo de Firmware (101fffff)
---------------------------------
identificador           {273a1041-4467-11eb-b947-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=F:
path                    \EFI\opensuse\shim.efi
description             opensuse-secureboot
isolatedcontext         Yes

Aplicativo de Firmware (101fffff)
---------------------------------
identificador           {e44d77c7-574c-11eb-b959-28cdc4f759f4}
device                  partition=B:
path                    \EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi
description             UEFI: IM2P33F3A NVMe ADATA 512GB, Partition 4
isolatedcontext         Yes
```

(let me know if you need more output from `bcdedit`)

P.S. Despite the output of `list vol` above, vol. B is considered as EFI System partition by my partitioning manager and also by `list part`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching further, I finally concluded that I could **not** delete the partition B (the one holding `\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi`) because partition A holds only Windows Boot **Manager**, which is accessed during boot in order to select the proper boot **loader** to execute (most relevant in case of dual-booted machines, for instance). The latter is actually the unit which is responsible for the boot of the OS, and in case of UEFI 64-bits Windows systems it turns to be usually the file `\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi` that I was considering to delete! References: this [askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165501/uefi-multi-booting-with-pre-existing-windows-installation), which points to this [useful web page](https://www.lifewire.com/efi-file-2620983).

The solution to my problem was given by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1091055) to another Superuser question. That question is not identical to my problem, but the solution pointed to by that last link fits perfectly in my case as well.