# Unable to boot system after removing disk 2 even if windows is installed on disk 1

Tags: boot, partitioning, efi

[image: Partition Information]

I have two hard disk, DISK 0 is SSD where windows is installed and DISK 1 is Mechanical HDD. I want to replace DISK 1 with another SSD, but when I remove Disk 1, I'm unable to boot the system (Message No bootable media found) even if windows is installed on DISK 0 I think that's because of an EFI System Partition on DISK 1.

Is there any way to replace Disk 1 with another disk and start the system without fresh installing windows?

Comment: https://www.tomica.net/blog/2020/04/move-efi-partition-to-another-drive-windows-10/

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/665923/move-efi-system-partition-to-another-drivehttps://superuser.com/questions/665923/move-efi-system-partition-to-another-drive

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1453790/how-to-move-the-recovery-partition-on-windows-10

Comment: Your boot partition and EFI is on disk 1If you remove disk 1 then your system is unable to boot into Windows. Create and then duplicate the required partitions on disk 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move the recovery partition on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1453790/how-to-move-the-recovery-partition-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tomica.net/blog/2020/04/move-efi-partition-to-another-drive-windows-10/

This link provided the help to move partition from disk1 to disk0. It solved my issue.