# Changing ZFS pool partition size on "advanced format" hard drives

Tags: linux, partitioning, zfs

I have a system running Ubuntu 13.04 with three [WD30EZRX](http://www.wdc.com/global/products/specs/?driveID=927) drives (3 TBs each) in a pool with raidz1.

These drives apparently have an "advanced format", but they misreport their physical block size.
This leads to horrible performance, especially when writing small files.

However, this can be easily fixed by letting the partition start at sector 2048 instead of 1, or 63.

Unfortunately, I did not know any of this when creating the pool, and now it's 93% filled.

Is there any way to resize the zfs partitions to start at sector 2048 without losing my data?

I can not export the pool, nor can I copy the files somewhere else and recreate the pool - I simply don't have more than ~2 TBs of space anywhere else.

Comment: So basically you want to move (shift) the partition from sector 63 to sector 2048?

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need to do, yes.

Comment: Then see [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/763324/2357) to question [Move partition data with dd to the right](http://superuser.com/q/737559/2357).